# PHP call function within an array

Tags: php, function

I need some help.

I have a simple BBCODE preg_replace function. When you quote a post I would like to call it like so:

> [QUOTE=POSTID][/QUOTE]

However to do this I need to call a function: quote_post($id)

```
    function quote_post($id) {
    if($id){
    $postgrabid = $core->clean( $id );  
    $query = $db->query( "SELECT * FROM `forum_posts` WHERE `postid`='{$postgrabid}'");
    $array = $db->assoc( $query );
    echo $array['content'];
    } else {
        // Quotes without POSTID
    }
}
```

Now this is a basic function as it doesn't carry out the relevant permission checks (because technically you could reference any post in the forum and see it). However I am trying to get my head round how I would do this first of all.

My BBCode function is:

```
    function bbc2html($content) {
  $search = array (
    '/(\[b\])(.*?)(\[\/b\])/',
    '/(\[B\])(.*?)(\[\/B\])/',
    '/(\[i\])(.*?)(\[\/i\])/',
    '/(\[I\])(.*?)(\[\/I\])/',
    '/(\[u\])(.*?)(\[\/u\])/',
    '/(\[U\])(.*?)(\[\/U\])/',
    '/(\[ul\])(.*?)(\[\/ul\])/',
    '/(\[li\])(.*?)(\[\/li\])/',
    '/(\[url=)(.*?)(\])(.*?)(\[\/url\])/',
    '/(\[url\])(.*?)(\[\/url\])/',
    '/(\[size=)(.*?)(\])(.*?)(\[\/size\])/',
    '/(\[SIZE=)(.*?)(\])(.*?)(\[\/SIZE\])/',
    '/(\[img\])(.*?)(\[\/img\])/',
    '/(\[IMG\])(.*?)(\[\/IMG\])/',
    '/(\[IMGR\])(.*?)(\[\/IMGR\])/',
    '/(\[imgr\])(.*?)(\[\/imgr\])/',
    '/(\[strike\])(.*?)(\[\/strike\])/',
    '/(\[STRIKE\])(.*?)(\[\/STRIKE\])/',
    '/(\[youtube\])(.*?)(\[\/youtube\])/',
    '/(\[YOUTUBE\])(.*?)(\[\/YOUTUBE\])/',
    '/(\[left\])(.*?)(\[\/left\])/',
    '/(\[LEFT\])(.*?)(\[\/LEFT\])/',
    '/(\[CENTER\])(.*?)(\[\/CENTER\])/',
    '/(\[center\])(.*?)(\[\/center\])/',
    '/(\[RIGHT\])(.*?)(\[\/RIGHT\])/',
    '/(\[right\])(.*?)(\[\/right\])/',
    '/(\[JUSTIFY\])(.*?)(\[\/JUSTIFY\])/',
    '/(\[justify\])(.*?)(\[\/justify\])/',
    '/(\[color=)(.*?)(\])(.*?)(\[\/color\])/',
    '/(\[COLOR=)(.*?)(\])(.*?)(\[\/COLOR\])/',
    '/(@\w+)/',
    '/(\[BADGE\])(.*?)(\[\/BADGE\])/',
    '/(\[badge\])(.*?)(\[\/badge\])/',
    '/(\[quote=)(.*?)(\])(.*?)(\[\/quote\])/',
    '/(\[QUOTE=)(.*?)(\])(.*?)(\[\/QUOTE\])/'
  );
  $replace = array (
    '<span style="font-weight: 700;">$2</span>',
    '<span style="font-weight: 700;">$2</span>',
    '<em>$2</em>',
    '<em>$2</em>',
    '<u>$2</u>',
    '<u>$2</u>',
    '<ul>$2</ul>',
    '<li>$2</li>',
    '<a href="$2" target="_blank">$4</a>',
    '<a href="$2" target="_blank">$4</a>',
'<span style="font-size: $2em!important;">$4</span>',
'<span style="font-size: $2em!important;">$4</span>',
    '<img src="$2" style="max-width: 100%;">',
    '<img src="$2" style="max-width: 100%;">',
    '<img src="$2" align="right">',
    '<img src="$2" align="right">',
    '<strike>$2</strike>',
    '<strike>$2</strike>',
    '<iframe width="500" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/$2?modestbranding=1" frameborder="0"></iframe>',
    '<iframe width="500" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/$2?modestbranding=1" frameborder="0"></iframe>',
    '<span class="left">$2</span>',
    '<span class="left">$2</span>',
    '<center$2</center>',
    '<center>$2</center>',
    '<span class="right">$2</span>',
    '<span class="right">$2</span>',
    '<span class="justify">$2</span>',
    '<span class="justify">$2</span>',
    '<span style="color: $2">$4</span>',
    '<span style="color: $2">$4</span>',
    '<span style="font-weight: 700;" class="onclick" onclick="profile(\'$1\')">$1</span>',
    '<div class="quest_badgedisplay"><img src="$2"></div>',
    '<div class="quest_badgedisplay"><img src="$2"></div>',
    'quote_post($2)',
    'quote_post($2)'
    );

  return preg_replace($search, $replace, $content);
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: why are you not using the bbcode functions in php?

Comment: The above code is PHP >_>

Comment: Remove the `'` from either side of `quote_post($2)`

Comment: I tried that and it causes an error / errors the forum threadview page @pokeybit

Comment: php has bbcode specific functions https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.bbcode.php no need to reinvent the wheel